# Equinox p2 Repository Mirroring: how to mirror only specific features?

Tags: eclipse, p2

The page http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring
describes how to use the two applications 
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication and
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication to mirror *entire* update sites to a local p2 repository.

This page also says: 
*"In addition, users can do selective mirroring of artifacts or metadata either to create a more specific mirror (e.g. only mirror latest code) or merge content into an existing mirror"* ,
but provides no further example or text on that subject.

So how do I mirror only parts of the source repository, e.g. a feature with a specific version?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have a look at the http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Ant_Tasks.

Next post might help as well: http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2012/11/mirror-eclipse-repositories-with-p2-mirror-ant-task/.